# Httpclient deprecated,httpResponse deperecated in android studio 1.5.1

Tags: android

i'm creating login and registration page and 'm facing problem,, the json result takes zero value...i've checked fulll code but i found in this htpclient ,httpparams are having strike out lines on them please fix

```
private class AsyncDataClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String > {

        @Override

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);

            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);

            String jsonResult = "";

            try {

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", params[1]));

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phoneno", params[2]));

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emailid", params[3]));

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", params[4]));

                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

                System.out.println("Returned Json object " + jsonResult.toString());

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return jsonResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this applicable: [HTTP Client removed from SDK 23](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

Here is my build script to workaround this issue:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    /* Apache HTTP Client has been removed from SDK Version 23 and up. Workaround See: https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client */
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```